# viewDidLoad and loadView questions

Tags: ios

I want to test the difference between viewDidLoad and loadView ,so i create a single view application and than set the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as flows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
//    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In my MyViewController's m file is as flows:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
}

@end
```

But the loadView method or viewDidLoad are not called.Why? But when i cancel the annotation at  the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions .they all are called.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the viewDidLoad is not called?

This behavior happens because your window is a nil. So your controller have not displayed and its view is not loaded.

Try this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
//    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

> Why the viewDidLoad is called if uncommented this line `viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`?

A view of an `UIViewController` is lazy loading. If you cancel the annotation at the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, although your controller have not displayed, but you have visit its `view` property then the view will to be loaded then going to be discarded.

Comment: It worked.I just find it too.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can i say that when we use self.view ,and if the view is nil ,the method loadView will call?

Comment: You are right. And the `viewDidLoad` will to be executed after `loadView`.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with simple example:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"test");
}

- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"load");
}

@end
```

And it works fine:

```
2015-08-16 13:18:46.163 Example[51603:406197] load
2015-08-16 13:18:46.164 Example[51603:406197] test
2015-08-16 13:18:46.164 Example[51603:406197] load
2015-08-16 13:18:46.164 Example[51603:406197] test
```

Here is delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [TestViewController new];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Update #1

I forgot about default storyboard I have. I don't use it but it is required for `window` property initialisation in delegate:

> Implementation of this property is required if your app’s Info.plist
>   file contains the UIMainStoryboardFile key. Fortunately, the Xcode
>   project templates usually include a synthesized declaration of the
>   property automatically for the app delegate. The default value of this
>   synthesized property is nil, which causes the app to create a generic
>   UIWindow object and assign it to the property. If you want to provide
>   a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of
>   this property and use it to create and return your custom window.

Comment: You can have a try:Deleting the storyboard or nib,and then run it

Comment: I think that much simple solution will be to have default storyboard. I don't use IB for UI but this makes things easy.

Comment: The point of the issue is window will not to be nil and the `view` property of the `UIViewController` is lazy loading.

Comment: @Bannings point of the issue is `window` property initialisation.

Comment: @JohnTracid The OP have 2 questions: 1. Why the `viewDidLoad` is not called? 2. Why the `viewDidLoad` is called if uncommented this line `viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`?

Comment: @Bannings so my answer is for first question.

Comment: @JohnTracid Yeah, I just want to say the storyboard is not the focus.

Answer (score 1):

"loadView" is called when self.view is called and self.view is nil, so if you uncomment

```
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

you literally call self.view, it would then call(internally) "loadView" and then "viewDidLoad".

I guess it is because "self.window" is not initialised, "loadView" and "viewDidLoad" are not called.